# Probability on the plane

Tags: probability, infinity

Problem. On the Cartesian plane with origin O and x- y-axes, I randomly pick a point P.  What is the probability that the line segment OP has a slope at least 1?

Is the answer 1/4 or 1/2?

answer = 1/4 :  divide the whole plane into 8 "equal" triangles like those in the UK flag.  2 of the 8 "equal" triangles have slope >= 1.

answer = 1/2 : i know for infinite stuff, part of it CAN equal to the whole.  i can make a bijection from the region with slope >= 1 to the region with slope <= 1 (divide the region with slope >= 1 into 3 parts and stretch clockwise).  This bijection means that the probability of choosing a point in two of the 8 triangles is the same as choosing in 6 of the 8 triangles?

(There is a similar question here about probability on infinite plane, but i don't understand what they mean by translation-invariant measure...)

Comment: The second answer is intuitively correct if the f(x)=x line truly divides the plane in two equal parts.

Comment: You can also make a bijection between the region with $\infty > slope > 1$ in the upper right quadrant of the plane and all of $\mathbb R$, that does not mean that you have probability $1$ of picking a point in that region. You need to understand some measure theory to resolve this as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You have to specify a probability distribution you're going to use to pick a random point. Note there is no "uniform" distribution that you can define on an infinite plane, and depending on your assumption on distribution, the results would naturally vary.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that each of the following are equally likely: slope greater than 1; slope between 0 and 1; slope between -1 and 0; and slope less than -1 (ignore the boundary cases as they don't affect the result). Each has probability 1/4.